# Mysql count if id not null

Tags: mysql

I want to count unread messages from the response table. the problem is, when no message exists according to the id in the where statement, it will count 0 and returns one row. That row must not be returned. any suggestions how to fix this issue?

```
SELECT m.*, COUNT(mr.id) as total_unread 
FROM `message` m 
LEFT JOIN message_response mr ON (mr.message_id = m.id) AND mr.read = 0
WHERE m.performance_report_id = :id
```

above statement will return if no message is found.

```
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0
```

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 3):

put your `m.performance_report_id = :id` in `ON Clause` instead of `where`

```
SELECT m.*, COUNT(mr.id) as total_unread 
FROM `message` m 
LEFT JOIN message_response mr ON (mr.message_id = m.id) AND mr.read = 0
and m.performance_report_id = :id
```

Comment: that's not working for me. This will return a single row that is not matching the performance_report_id.